# Idempotent entire complex function problem

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem statement**

Find all the entire functions $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$, that satisfy $f(f(z))=f(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb C$.

I have no idea how to attack this problem, I would appreciate hints and suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints: (Just throwing some things out there that you can use. Quite a few ways to solve it)

**(1)** Think about the identity function

**(2)** [Identity theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem)

**(3)** Think about the range of $f$, also consider the following: If two continuous functions $f, g : X → Y$ into a Hausdorff space $Y$ agree on a dense subset of $X$ then they agree on all of $X$.

**(4)** If an entire function is bounded then it has to be constant, see [Liouville's theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_%28complex_analysis%29)

Comment: Very useful hints, I'll stick to (1),(2) and (4) since I still haven't learnt about Hausdorff spaces. The identity function is one of the functions that satisfies the conditions required. By (4), an entire bounded function is constant. Let's see if constant functions satisfy the requirements of the statement: if $f$ is constant, then $f(z)=c$ for all $z$, we have $f(c)=f(f(z))=f(z)=c$, which is true. So, up to now we now that the identity function and constant functions belong to the set we are studying. It remains to analyze all the unbounded functions which are not the identity.

Comment: @PandaBear I still don't know how to use (2). If $f$ is an unbounded entire function such that $f(f(z))=f(z)$, then $f=Id$ on the set Im(f),i.e., this function coincides with the identity function in all the points of its image. To conclude that $f$ is exactly the identity function, I must show that $f=Id$ on a non-empty open subset of $\mathbb C$, but all I know is that $f=Id$ on $Im(f)$.

Comment: It can be proved that the range of a non-constant entire function is dense in $ \mathbb{C}$ . This can be proven with the help of Liouville's theorem.

Comment: I'll search a proof of that statement, but suppose we assume this is true, then what can I conclude from the fact that $Im(f)$ is dense in $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Well, then you also know that it agrees with the identity function on this dense subset and from that they agree on all $\mathbb{C}$

Comment: Thank you very much!, your hints were of great help, I couldn't follow some of them because I have to study more theory.

Answer (score 3):

I think this could work: assuming $f(z)$ is not constant, and considering the points where $f'(z) \neq 0$ , we have : $$f'(f(z))f'(z)=f'(z) $$, so that $f'(f(z))=1$. Since the range of $f(z)$ *, since the zeros of an analytic point are isolated) contains a limit point in $\mathbb C$, we can use the identity theorem on $f'(z)$.

(actually, the set where $f'(z) \neq 0$, which contains a limit point in $\mathbb C$.

Edit: We have shown that :
1)the two functions $f'$ and $1$ agree on the subset of the plane $f(z): z \in \mathbb C -Z$, where $Z$ is the set of points where $f'(z)=$.( The reason we exclude $Z$ is that , in order to derive the condition $f'(f(z))=1$, we divided both sides by $f'(z)$, so we want to avoid division by zero).

2)Now, we want to apply the identity theorem, so we must show that the set $f(z)$, where the two functions agree, has a limit point in $\mathbb C$. One way of doing this is by using Panda Bear's suggestion, using Picard's theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem , which states that the image of an entire function is dense in the plane.

Comment: I am trying to understand these things: why can I use the identity theorem on $f'(z)$? what this has to do with the fact that the set $\{z:f'(z) \neq 0\}$ has a limit point and why this set has a limit point? Sorry if these are too obvious questions but I really want to fully understand the key points of your proof.

Comment: @user100106: The identity theorem says that two analytic functions that agree on a subset that contain a limit point are equal to each other in the whole plane. I tried to argue that the functions $f'(z)$ and $1$ satisfy this condition: I excluded $Z$:= {$z: f'(z)=0$} , to be able to divide in the identity. Then the expression $f'(f(z))=1$ tells me that the functions $f'$ and $1$ agree on the range of $f(z)$. Now we just have to show ( for the Id. Thm) that the set{ $f(z)$}-$Z$ has a limit point in the plane. There are many ways of doing this; do you want me to give you a proof?

Comment: Yes, I would appreciate that since I am having some difficulty carrying out these details for myself. I've read about the identity theorem but the hypothesis was $f=g$ on an open non-empty subset, I didn't have any idea about this version using limit points instead of open subsets.

Comment: @user100106: Please see the edit and let me know if this is clearer.

Comment: Yes, now I could follow all the steps. Thanks!

Comment: @user100106: The set $\mathbb C \setminus Z$ is open, hence its image under  a non-constant  $f$ is open too and thus entire functions coinciding on that image coincide everywhere, according to the identity theorem in the form that you know.